# Creating modelformset instances initialised from database objects

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, inline-formset

I have a setup at the moment with a series of Objects in my database of type `CellType`.

What I seem to need is the [inline formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets), which apparently simplifies working with foreign key relationships between models.

What I want is a formset, consisting one form for each of a CellCount instance, linked to each of a CellType object in the database.

```
cellcount_formset = inlineformset_factory(CellType, 
                                          CellCount,
                                          form=CellCountForm,
                                          can_delete=False)
```

seems to take me a little in the right direction, but really what I want is to populate the CellCountForm's cell field with the correct CellType object, allowing the whole thing to be neatly packaged up and saved. This is proving a little more complex than I'd realised!

**models.py**

```
class CellType(models.Model):
    readable_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    machine_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    comment = models.TextField(blank=True)

class CellCount(models.Model):
    cell_count_instance = models.ForeignKey(CellCountInstance)
    cell = models.ForeignKey(CellType)
    normal_count = models.IntegerField()
    abnormal_count = models.IntegerField()
    comment = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class CellCountForm(ModelForm):
    auto_id = False

    class Meta:
        model = CellCount
        widgets = {
                'cell': HiddenInput(),
                'normal_count': HiddenInput,
                'abnormal_count': HiddenInput}
        exclude = ('cell_count_instance', 'comment',)
```

The widgets are hidden as they are populated by a JQuery based calculator behind the scenes.

Ideally the pseudocode logic I'm going for is:

```
formset containing:
    (x) CellCount forms, 
        the cell field of which is populated with the CellType object
        (x) = number of CellTypes in the database
```

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, you need to remove this `extra=len(get_celltype_list())`, which
is not what you want. This will create N(where N==len(get_celltype_list())) **additional** empty forms.